# Python 3 Threaded websockets server

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

I'm building a Websocket server application in python 3. I'm using this implementation: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/

Basically I want to manage multiple client.
Also I want to send data from 2 different thread (one for GPS + one for IMU)
GPS thread is refreshed 1Hz, while IMU thread is refresh at 25Hz

My problem is in MSGWorker.sendData method: as soon as I uncomment the line @asyncio.coroutine and yield from websocket.send('{"GPS": "%s"}' % data) the whole method does nothing (no print("Send data: foo") in terminal)

However with these two line commented my code works as I expect except that I send nothing through the websocket.

But, of course, my goal is to send data through the websocket, I just don't understand why it doesn't work ? Any idea ?

server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal, sys
sys.path.append('.')
import time
import websockets
import asyncio
import threading

connected = set()
stopFlag = False



class GPSWorker (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.data = 0
    self.lastData = 0
    self.inc = 0

  # Simulate GPS data
  def run(self):
    while not stopFlag:
      self.data = self.inc
      self.inc += 1
      time.sleep(1)

  def get(self):
    if self.lastData is not self.data:
      self.lastData = self.data
      return self.data



class IMUWorker (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.data = 0
    self.lastData = 0
    self.inc = 0

  # Simulate IMU data
  def run(self):
    while not stopFlag:
      self.data = self.inc
      self.inc += 1
      time.sleep(0.04)

  def get(self):
    if self.lastData is not self.data:
      self.lastData = self.data
      return self.data



class MSGWorker (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    while not stopFlag:
      data = gpsWorker.get()
      if data:
        self.sendData('{"GPS": "%s"}' % data)          

      data = imuWorker.get()
      if data:
        self.sendData('{"IMU": "%s"}' % data)

      time.sleep(0.04)

  #@asyncio.coroutine
  def sendData(self, data):
    for websocket in connected.copy():
      print("Sending data: %s" % data)
      #yield from websocket.send('{"GPS": "%s"}' % data)



@asyncio.coroutine
def handler(websocket, path):
  global connected
  connected.add(websocket)
  #TODO: handle client disconnection
  # i.e connected.remove(websocket)



if __name__ == "__main__":
  print('aeroPi server')
  gpsWorker = GPSWorker()
  imuWorker = IMUWorker()
  msgWorker = MSGWorker()

  try:
    gpsWorker.start()
    imuWorker.start()
    msgWorker.start()

    start_server = websockets.serve(handler, 'localhost', 7700)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
    loop.run_forever()

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stopFlag = True
    loop.close()
    print("Exiting program...")
```

client.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7700", 'json');
  ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(data);
  };
</script>
```

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 8):

Finally I got it !
It required Python 3.5.1 (while my distro provide only 3.4.3) and some help from Aymeric, the author of the websockets library (thanks to him).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal, sys
sys.path.append('.')
import time
import websockets
import asyncio
import threading


stopFlag = False



class GPSWorker (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.data = 0
    self.lastData = 0
    self.inc = 0

  # Simulate GPS data
  def run(self):
    while not stopFlag:
      self.data = self.inc
      self.inc += 1
      time.sleep(1)

  def get(self):
    if self.lastData is not self.data:
      self.lastData = self.data
      return self.data



class IMUWorker (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.data = 0
    self.lastData = 0
    self.inc = 0

  # Simulate IMU data
  def run(self):
    while not stopFlag:
      self.data = self.inc
      self.inc += 1
      time.sleep(0.04)

  def get(self):
    if self.lastData is not self.data:
      self.lastData = self.data
      return self.data



class MSGWorker (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.connected = set()

  def run(self):
    while not stopFlag:
      data = gpsWorker.get()
      if data:
        self.sendData('{"GPS": "%s"}' % data)

      data = imuWorker.get()
      if data:
        self.sendData('{"IMU": "%s"}' % data)

      time.sleep(0.04)

  async def handler(self, websocket, path):
    self.connected.add(websocket)
    try:
      await websocket.recv()
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
      pass
    finally:
      self.connected.remove(websocket)

  def sendData(self, data):
    for websocket in self.connected.copy():
      print("Sending data: %s" % data)
      coro = websocket.send(data)
      future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)



if __name__ == "__main__":
  print('aeroPi server')
  gpsWorker = GPSWorker()
  imuWorker = IMUWorker()
  msgWorker = MSGWorker()

  try:
    gpsWorker.start()
    imuWorker.start()
    msgWorker.start()

    ws_server = websockets.serve(msgWorker.handler, '0.0.0.0', 7700)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(ws_server)
    loop.run_forever()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stopFlag = True
    #TODO: close ws server and loop correctely
    print("Exiting program...")
```

Regards,
Clément

Comment: It's been a while since you posted the answer. Have you maybe developed your solution? I am doing something similar at the moment and would like to save myself some trouble :)

Comment: How did you end up closing your ws server and loop? I'm having some threads hanging when the `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised.

Comment: @DC_ACexcept KeyboardInterrupt:
    stopFlag = True
    ws_server.close()
    loop.stop()
    print("Exiting program...")

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I am trying to mimic the functionality and I figured someone may be willing to lend a hand.

I have two CAN busses so I want one thread for each. I will later have more threads for a web socket connection and possibly other computational tasks.

The code gets stuck in the infinite while loop when I call run on the can0worker. I'm not familiar enough with python multithreading to know how to fix it. I thought that the while loop, because it is on a separate thread, is non-blocking but mine is blocking from the testing that I have done.

```
class CANWorker (threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, channel_num):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.msg = None
    self.lastmsg = None
    self.channel_num = channel_num
    print("init", self.channel_num)
    os.system(f'sudo ifconfig can{channel_num} down')
    os.system(f'sudo ip link set can{channel_num} up type can bitrate 2000000   dbitrate 8000000 restart-ms 1000 berr-reporting on fd on')
    os.system(f'sudo ifconfig can{channel_num} txqueuelen 65536')
    self.can = can.interface.Bus(channel = f'can{channel_num}', bustype = 'socketcan', fd=True)

def run(self):
    print("run", self.channel_num)
    while not stopFlag:
        self.msg = self.can.recv(0.01)
    
def get(self):
    print("get", self.channel_num)
    if self.lastmsg is not self.msg:
        self.lastmsg = self.msg
        return self.msg
```

---

Call this within `if __name__ == "__main__"`:

```
can0worker = CANWorker(0)
can1worker = CANWorker(1)
can0worker.run()
can1worker.run()
```

---

Results after running

```
init 0

init 1

run 0
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like your code to run workers is incorrect, I invite you to read carefully my response [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216830)    
More precisely, read my ```if __name__ == "__main__":``` section where you can see I call `gpsWorker.start()` while you call `can0worker.run()`. This is incorrect

Comment: That was it. Man, sometimes you just have a moment of ineptitude. Thanks for reviewing.