# Simple websocket server in Python for publishing

Tags: python, api, websocket, publish-subscribe

I have a running CLI application in Python that uses threads to execute some workers. Now I am writing a GUI using electron for this application. For simple requests/responses I am using `gRPC` to communicate between the Python application and the GUI.

I am, however, struggling to find a proper publishing mechanism to push data to the GUI: `gRPC`s integrated streaming won't work since it uses generators; as already mentioned my longer, blocking tasks are executed using threads (subclasses of `threading.Thread`). Also I'd like to emit certain events (e.g., the progress) from within those threads.

Then I've found the `Flasks` SocketIO implementation, which is, however, a blocking execution and thus not really suited for what I have in mind - I'd have to again execute two processes (Flask and my CLI application)...

Another package I've found is `websockets` but I can't get my head around how I could implement this `producer()` function that they mention in the [patterns](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#producer).

My last idea would be to deploy a broker-based message system like `Redis` or simply fall back to the brokerless `zmq`, which is a bit of a hassle to setup for the GUI application.

#### So the simple question:

Is there any easy framework that allows to create a server-"task" in a Python that I can pass messages to publish to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with concurrency in python:

No, there isn't any simple framework. IMHO pythons' concurrency handling is a bit of a mess (compared to other languages like `golang`, where concurrency is built in). There's multiple major packages implementing this, one of them `asyncio`, but most of them are incompatible. I've ended up using a similar solution like proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172006/python-3-threaded-websockets-server).